# SQL-Server An aggregate (Count) may not appear in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im my query I get the following error message:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

My query is following:

```
SELECT f.ID as IdFlight
From Flights as f 
inner join BookingsFlightsPassenger as b on f.ID = b.ID_flight
WHERE count(b.ID_Flight)<100
```

How can I solve this? I am not sure what the error message is suggesting

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `HAVING` and add `GROUP BY f.ID `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace "where" by "having" and add group by

```
SELECT f.ID as IdFlight
From Flights as f inner join BookingsFlightsPassenger as b on f.ID = b.ID_flight
group by f.id
having count(b.ID_Flight)<100
```

Comment: This works however my query was a simplified sample of the true one and i need also to insert other where conditions. Where do I add them?

Comment: @user1238784 - in a where clause. Where is for predicates to be applied before aggregation - a having clause is for predicates that are to be applied after aggregation

Comment: my original query is:
SELECT f.ID as IdFlight, Tarif * 2 as Tarif, f.Time, sl.Name as FromLoc, sl.Country as FromCountry,
sl.Airport as FromAirport,dl.Name as ToLoc, dl.Country as ToCountry, dl.Airport as ToAirport 
FROM Flights as f INNER JOIN Locations as sl ON sl.ID = f.ID_Source 
INNER JOIN Locations as dl ON dl.ID = f.ID_Destination 
INNER JOIN FlightsTarifs as ftf ON f.Id = ftf.IDFlight 
inner join BookingsFlightsPassenger as b on f.ID = b.ID_flight
WHERE count(b.ID_Flight)<100 AND f.ID_Destination =2 AND f.Time >= '2018/05/16 00:00'
How do I change it?

Comment: I have tried:
SELECT f.ID as IdFlight, Tarif * 2 as Tarif, f.Time, sl.Name as FromLoc, etc...
FROM Flights as f inner join BookingsFlightsPassenger as b on f.ID = b.ID_flight
INNER JOIN Locations as sl ON sl.ID = f.ID_Source 
INNER JOIN Locations as dl ON dl.ID = f.ID_Destination 
INNER JOIN FlightsTarifs as ftf ON f.Id = ftf.IDFlight 
Where f.ID_Destination =2 
AND f.Time <= DATEADD(day,4,'2018/05/16 00:00') 
AND f.Time >= '2018/05/16 00:00' 
Group by f.id
having count(b.ID_Flight)<100  
ORDER By f.Time, Tarif

Comment: But I get error: Column 'FlightsTarifs.Tarif' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function  or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: in "where" use column conditions, in "having" use conditions on aggregate fuctions

Comment: Try to avoid answering a question that has been answered in the comment section... There is a reason this man has not answered the question by posting an answer cause its simply not worth an answer. This is pure you going for rep

Comment: I accepted your answer, but please can you help me with the error about the tarif column?

Comment: I would expect the result was that I have plenty of Flights, since the BookingsFlightsPassenger table is empty, but I get 0 results from the query. What I want to do is to get all the flights that have enough free seats to be booked. In the bookings table are stored the Id of flights already booked. So when the count of flightId reaches 100 it means that flight is full and should not appear in the results. But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: you need to add every result column do group by  (Id, tarif...)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to write this query doesn't use a `join`:

```
SELECT bfp.ID_flight as as IdFlight
FROM BookingsFlightsPassenger bfp
GROUP BY bfp.ID_flight
WHERE count(*) < 100;
```